# Swift protocol called in Objective-C not working and application crashes with error message "unrecognized selector"

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates

I am trying to get the Swift protocol to work in Objective-C file, but the application crashes when the error as below.

```
+[OpenCamera onCameraClose]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x102ff8580
```

I am not sure as to what I am missing.

//Swift: UIViewController Code

```
@objc protocol CameraViewControllerDelegate {
    func onCameraClose()
}

@objc class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
   var delegate : CameraViewControllerDelegate? = nil
   func closeCamera(sender: Any) {
     delegate?.onCameraClose()
   }
}
```

// Objective-C : UIViewController Code

OpenCamera.h

```
@interface OpenCamera : UIViewController <CameraViewControllerDelegate>
```

OpenCamera.m

```
#import <MyProjectName/MyProjectName-Swift.h>
@implementation OpenCamera

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CameraViewController *cameraViewController = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraView" bundle:nil];
    cameraViewController.delegate = self; //Warning - Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<CameraViewControllerDelegate> _Nullable' from 'Class'
}
- (void)onCameraClose {
    NSLog(@"Swift Protocol method executed from Objective-C");
}
@end
```

Comment: The warning `Warning - Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<CameraViewControllerDelegate> _Nullable' from 'Class'` did in fact predict this.

Comment: There is something wrong with your `import` and _.m_ / _.h_ arrangement but you have not shown enough information for us to know what it is. How was _OpenCamera.h_ able to mention a protocol that is not imported except in the _.m_ file? How was it able to see a `delegate` property that is not declared `@objc`? Something is very wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The warning here did in fact predict the crash:

```
cameraViewController.delegate = self; 
//Warning - Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<CameraViewControllerDelegate> _Nullable' from 'Class'
```

Clearly it thinks `self` is a class, not an instance. That's very odd.

My guess is that there is something wrong with your `import` arrangements, but you have not shown enough information to see what it is. I'll just show an arrangement that works.

Let's assume you have both Objective-C and Swift code in one target (i.e. that no frameworks are involved). Then in Swift, you say:

```
@objc protocol CameraViewControllerDelegate {
    func onCameraClose()
}

class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
   @objc var delegate : CameraViewControllerDelegate? = nil
   func closeCamera(sender: Any) {
     delegate?.onCameraClose()
   }
}
```

Note the use of `@objc var` to expose the `delegate` property. There is no need to expose the class to Objective-C, as it is already an NSObject derivative.

Okay, in Objective-C, here is your interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OpenCamera : UIViewController

@end
```

Note that you do *not* import the generated header in a *.h* file, and you do *not* attempt to mention an imported protocol here.

On to the implementation file:

```
#import "OpenCamera.h"
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

@interface OpenCamera () <CameraViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation OpenCamera

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CameraViewController *cameraViewController = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraView" bundle:nil];
    cameraViewController.delegate = self;
}
- (void)onCameraClose {
    NSLog(@"Swift Protocol method executed from Objective-C");
}
@end
```

We import the corresponding *.h* file and the generated header *.h* file here. We use an anonymous category to declare conformance to the protocol, and the rest is as you have it. You won't see any warnings.